# How to Catch rendering errors while Prerendering in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using **renderModuleFactory** from **@angular/platform-server** to pre render the html pages. 
I am having 100's of routes to pre render.
But for some routes the api call in component is failing with error at some time, and rendering the page without full content, How can i catch these routes to re process?